# How come id will not pass through link?

Tags: php, html

I have a simple link that needs to pass a variable through $_GET and set it to a variable in the page that is being opened. It is failing every time however and I am not sure why.

```
 <a class='section_header' href='category/index.php?`id='" . $catid . "'><b>" . $row[0] ."</b></a>
```

Code in category/index.php

```
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  echo $id;
```

Comment: That ` does not belong there...

Comment: Look at 'view source' in your developer tools in your browser. you should be able to easily spot where it went wrong. There's several quotes in the wrong place. Think of how the link _should_ look like in HTML, that might help you get it right in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a class='section_header' href="category/index.php?id=<?php echo $catid?>"><b><?php echo $row[0];?></b></a>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<a class='section_header' href='category/index.php?id='" . $catid . "'><b>" . $row[0] ."</b></a>
```

You had a random ` in there. Once it prints out you can use inspect element to make sure the url looks correct and id is populated.